How to get high throughput with warp
I am setting up my first api using the Rust warp crate, and I can't get anywhere close to the performance I was hoping for.
To eliminate issues with my implementation, I added a simple route like this:
async fn ping() -> Result<impl Reply, Rejection> {
    Ok(html("pong"))
}

pub fn routes(app: Arc<App>) -> impl Filter<Extract = impl Reply, Error = Rejection> + Clone {
    path!("v1" / "pub" / "ping")
        .and(get())
        .and_then(ping)
}

When I curl this endpoint I get the result I expect, but when I try to test with some load using JMeter, the maximum throughput I can get is about 2000 requests/sec, and for anything over a few hundred requests/sec JMeter records a high ratio of errors (60%+).
The JMeter errors all say "Connection refused". It looks like warp/hyper is refusing connections when handling many requests rather than returning 503 responses which is one issue, but more importantly, during this load test my CPU is below 5%, and 2000 requests/sec is quite poor.
The web benchmark site claims 500,000 requests/sec so I must be missing something, but this is a very basic setup.
-- EDIT --
To eliminate JMeter from the equation, I wrote this Rust test client, and was able to get up to 7,000 requests/sec, but it's still not startling.
use core::fmt;
use std::error::Error;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::time::Instant;

use hyper::{Request, StatusCode};
use hyper_util::rt::TokioIo;
use bytes::Bytes;
use http_body_util::Empty;
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio::task;

type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>>;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let url = "http://localhost:8000/v1/pub/ping".parse::<hyper::Uri>()?;
    let concurrency = 20;
    let repeat_count = 500;

    let authority = url.authority().unwrap();

    let addr = Arc::new(String::from(authority.as_str()));
    let req = Arc::new(Request::builder()
        .method("GET")
        .uri(url.path())
        .header(hyper::header::HOST, authority.as_str())
        .header(hyper::header::CONNECTION, "keep-alive")
        .body(Empty::<Bytes>::new())?);

    // Warm up the connection
    fetch(addr.clone(), req.clone()).await?;

    let start = Instant::now();

    let mut tasks = Vec::new();

    for _ in 0..concurrency {
        tasks.push(task::spawn(fetch(addr.clone(), req.clone())));
    }

    for _ in 1..repeat_count {
        for _ in 0..concurrency {
            let task = tasks.remove(0);
            let _ = task.await?;
            tasks.push(task::spawn(fetch(addr.clone(), req.clone())));
        }
    }

    for task in tasks {
        let _ = task.await?;
    }

    let elapsed = start.elapsed();
    println!("Elapsed: {:.2?} GET {} {} times with {} concurrency", elapsed, url, concurrency * repeat_count, concurrency);
    println!("Average {} req/sec", 1000 * concurrency * repeat_count / elapsed.as_millis());

    Ok(())
}

async fn fetch(addr: Arc<String>, req: Arc<Request<Empty<Bytes>>>) -> Result<()> {
    let stream = TcpStream::connect(&*addr).await?;
    let io = TokioIo::new(stream);
    
    let (mut sender, conn) = hyper::client::conn::http1::handshake(io).await?;
    task::spawn(async move {
        if let Err(err) = conn.await {
            println!("Connection failed: {:?}", err);
        }
    });

    let res = sender.send_request((*req).clone()).await?;

    match res.status() {
        StatusCode::OK => Ok(()),
        _ => Err(Box::new(HttpError::new(res.status()))) 
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct HttpError {
    pub status: StatusCode,
}

impl HttpError {
    pub fn new(status: StatusCode) -> Self {
        Self { status }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for HttpError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Http status code {}", self.status )
    }
}

impl Error for HttpError {
    fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn Error + 'static)> { None }
    fn description(&self) -> &str { "" }
    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&dyn Error> { self.source() }
}

-- EDIT --
Just for the hell of it, I decided to write a bare bones web server using just std. It is slightly better than warp, serving about 7,500 requests/sec. This is the code:
use crate::App;
use std::{
    io::{prelude::*, BufReader},
    net::{Ipv4Addr, TcpListener, TcpStream},
    sync::{atomic::Ordering, mpsc, Arc},
    thread::{self, available_parallelism, Thread},
};

pub fn run(app: Arc<App>, ipv4: Ipv4Addr, port: u16) {
    let authority = format!("{}:{}", ipv4, port);
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(authority).unwrap();

    let concurrency = available_parallelism().unwrap().get();
    let mut threads: Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>> = Vec::with_capacity(concurrency);
    let mut senders: Vec<mpsc::Sender<TcpStream>> = Vec::with_capacity(concurrency);

    for _ in 0..concurrency {
        let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
        senders.push(sender);

        let app = app.clone();
        threads.push(thread::spawn(move || process_connections(app, receiver)))
    }

    let mut thread_index = 0;
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        senders[thread_index].send(stream.unwrap()).unwrap();
        thread_index = (thread_index + 1) % concurrency;
    }
}

fn process_connections(app: Arc<App>, receiver: mpsc::Receiver<TcpStream>) {
    loop {
        let stream = receiver.recv().unwrap();
        handle_connection(app.clone(), stream);
    }
}

fn handle_connection(app: Arc<App>, mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let buf_reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
    let _http_request: Vec<_> = buf_reader
        .lines()
        .map(|result| result.unwrap())
        .take_while(|line| !line.is_empty())
        .collect();

    let response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
    stream.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();

    app.clone()
        .request_count
        .clone()
        .fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
}

Maybe the problem is on the client side, or maybe this is just some fundamental limit of my MacBook pro. It's a mystery.
Maybe I will try streaming multiple requests over a single connection and see how that works.

Are you running in --release mode?

I tried with and without the --release flag and it makes a difference of a few percent. After seeing the benchmark results I was expecting at least 10X what I am seeing, so --release isn't going to do it.

A couple of days later, and I now know exactly what's going on. The problem is that hyper does not support keep-alive correctly. I figured this out by writing a client application that uses low level sockets. I could see that the server (I tried warp, and also directly using hyper) closes the connection after the first request regardless of whether I pass the keep-alive header or not.
After discovering this, I wrote the server side using sockets as well, and implemented keep-alive properly, and this solution processes 70,000 requests/sec.
I'm still not sure how the web framework benchmarks claim 500,000 requests/sec unless they are running on very big machines with 10's of physical cores, but I am quite satisfied with 70k req/sec on my MacBook pro.
I guess the answer to my original question of how to make warp fast, is to fix the keep-alive issues in hyper.
For anyone that wants to try this, here is my code:
Server:
use std::{
    io::{
        prelude::*, BufReader, BufWriter
    }, 
    net::{Ipv4Addr, TcpListener, TcpStream}, 
    sync::{atomic::Ordering, mpsc, Arc}, 
    thread::{self, available_parallelism}
};
use crate::App;

pub fn run(app: Arc<App>, ipv4: Ipv4Addr, port: u16) {
    let authority = format!("{}:{}", ipv4, port);
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(authority).unwrap();

    let concurrency = available_parallelism().unwrap().get();
    let mut threads: Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>> = Vec::with_capacity(concurrency);
    let mut senders: Vec<mpsc::Sender<TcpStream>> = Vec::with_capacity(concurrency);

    for index in 0..concurrency {
        let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
        senders.push(sender);

        let app = app.clone();
        threads.push(thread::spawn(move || process_connections(app, receiver, index + 1)))
    }

    let mut thread_index = 0;
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        senders[thread_index].send(stream.unwrap()).unwrap();
        thread_index = (thread_index + 1) % concurrency;
    }
}

fn process_connections(app: Arc<App>, receiver: mpsc::Receiver<TcpStream>, index: usize) {
    loop {
        let stream = receiver.recv().unwrap();
        handle_connection(app.clone(), stream, index);
    }
}

fn handle_connection(app: Arc<App>, stream: TcpStream, index: usize) {
    let mut request_lines = BufReader::new(&stream)
        .lines()
        .map(|result| match result {
            Ok(line) => line,
            Err(err) => {
                println!("{}# {}", index, err);
                String::default()
            },
        });

    let mut response_writer = BufWriter::new(&stream);

    loop {
        let mut keep_alive = false;
        
        let http_request = extract_request(&mut request_lines);

        if http_request.len() == 0 {
            return;
        } else {
            for line in http_request {
                if line.to_lowercase() == "connection: keep-alive" { 
                    keep_alive = true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        let response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n".as_bytes();
        match response_writer.write_all(response) {
            Ok(_) => { 
                response_writer.flush();
            },
            Err(err) => {
                println!("{}# Err writing response to stream: {}", index, err);
                return;
            }
        };

        app.clone().request_count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
        
        if !keep_alive { 
            return
        }
    }
}

fn extract_request(lines: &mut impl Iterator<Item = String>) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    loop {
        match lines.next() {
            Some(line) => { 
                if line.len() == 0 { return result; }
                result.push(line);
            },
            None => { return result; }
        }
    }
}

Client:
use std::{
    io::{BufRead, BufReader, BufWriter, Write}, 
    net::TcpStream, 
    thread::{self, available_parallelism}, 
    time::Instant
};

pub async fn run_test() -> super::Result<()> {
    let authority = "localhost:8000";
    let path = "/v1/admin/nodes";
    let repeat_count: usize = 100000;
    let concurrency = available_parallelism().unwrap().get();

    let request_text = format!("GET {} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {}\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n", path, authority);

    let start = Instant::now();

    let mut threads: Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>> = Vec::with_capacity(concurrency);
    for _ in 0..concurrency {
        let request = request_text.clone();
        threads.push(thread::spawn(move || make_request(authority, repeat_count, request.as_bytes())));
    }
    for thread in threads {
        thread.join();
    }

    let elapsed = start.elapsed();
    println!(
        "Elapsed: {:.2?} GET {}{} {} times with {} concurrency",
        elapsed,
        authority,
        path,
        concurrency * repeat_count,
        concurrency
    );
    println!(
        "Average {} req/sec",
        ((concurrency * repeat_count) as f32 / (elapsed.as_micros() as f32 / 1000000.0)).floor()
    );

    Ok(())
}

fn make_request(authority: &str, count: usize, request: &[u8]) {
    let stream = TcpStream::connect(authority).unwrap();

    let mut response_lines = BufReader::new(&stream)
        .lines()
        .map(|result| match result {
            Ok(line) => line,
            Err(err) => {
                println!("{}", err);
                String::default()
            },
        });

    let mut request_writer = BufWriter::new(&stream);

    for _ in 0..count {
        request_writer.write_all(&request).unwrap();
        request_writer.flush().unwrap();

        let _ = extract_response(&mut response_lines);
    }
}

fn extract_response(lines: &mut impl Iterator<Item = String>) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    loop {
        match lines.next() {
            Some(line) => { 
                if line.len() == 0 { return result; }
                result.push(line);
            },
            None => { return result; }
        }
    }
}



You might want to check out the value of actix_web::HttpServer::max_connections, however default is 25000 and it is many more than 2000.
JMeter also needs to be configured for high loads, make sure to follow instructions from 9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure article
Your operating system might have its own limits in terms of TCP timeouts, recycling and number of available ephemeral ports so you might want to check and eventually increase it


OP is using Warp, not Actix-Web

I am running this on M2 MacBook Pro with 10 cores. It's a pretty fast machine.
If I run my test with too many requests, then I do run out of ephemeral ports as expected.

run ulimit -u and you will see how many processes your "pretty fast" machine can run

ulimit -u returns 2666
